# questions Inserting in heapsort

Tags: java, algorithm, insert, heapsort

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MaxHeap
{
   private ArrayList<Student> students;

   public MaxHeap(int capacity)
   {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>(capacity);
   }

   public MaxHeap(Collection<Student> collection)
   {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>(collection);
      for(int i = size()/2; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         maxHeapify(i);
      }
   }

   public Student getMax()
   {
      if(size() < 1)
      {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No maximum value:  the heap is empty.");
      }
      return students.get(0);
   }

   public Student extractMax()
   {
      Student value = getMax();
      students.set(0,students.get(size()-1));
      students.remove(size()-1);
      maxHeapify(0);
      return value;
   }


   public void insert(Student elt)
   {

       private int lastOne;

       if (lastOne ==  students.length)
           throw new heapException("heap is full");
       else {
           // I'm stuck here

       }
   }
```

As I understand, I Insert the element at last. Then compare it with its parent.
If parent is greater than this latest insertion, return the element.
Else swap parent and this child

```
    private int parent(int index)
   {
      return (index - 1)/2;
   }

   private int left(int index)
   {
      return 2 * index + 1;
   }

   private int right(int index)
   {
      return 2 * index + 2;
   }

   private int size()
   {
      return students.size();
   }

   private void swap(int from, int to)
   {
      Student val = students.get(from);
      students.set(from,  students.get(to));
      students.set(to,  val);
   }

   private void maxHeapify(int index)
   {
      int left = left(index);
      int right = right(index);
      int largest = index;
      if (left <  size() && students.get(left).compareTo(students.get(largest)) > 0)
      {
         largest = left;
      }
      if (right <  size() && students.get(right).compareTo(students.get(largest)) > 0)
      {
         largest = right;
      }
      if (largest != index)
      {
         swap(index, largest);
         maxHeapify(largest);
      }  
   }   
}
```

Thank you everybody, now i can make a children and parent node, but How can add insert method ? I think about while or if statement. But cannot fingure out...

Answer (score 0):

Think about what a heap is ... a COMPLETE tree.

```
                           0
                        1     2
                      3   4
```

So the children of index 0 are index 1 and 2, the children of index 1 are 3 and 4, the children of index 2 are 5 and 6. See a pattern?

EDIT: also you should use generics for a heap, that is the reason why you are supposed to use an ArrayList in java and not a standard array. A generic heap will allow an argument to be past to determine the type so the structure is more flexible.

Comment: If you are not familiar with generics and this is hw then don't worry about it unless you are curious (then google java generics or look at api). If this is hw I suggest avoiding this website at least until you have covered the basics. Programming is about problem solving and if answers are handed to you, you are doing yourself a disservice. That being said, the insert method inserts at the last index and "bubbles up" meaning it swaps with its parent until it is at the appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

In a 0-based binary heap, given a node at index `i`:

- The left child is at index `(i * 2) + 1`
- The right child is at index `(i * 2) + 2`
- The parent is at index `(i - 1)/2`

To insert, you add the item as the last item in the array, and then you move it up the heap, continually comparing with the parent. Like this:

```
public void insert(Student elt)
{
    students.add(elt);
    int i = students.size()-1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        int p = parent(i);
        if (students[i] >= students[p])
        {
            // item is not smaller than parent, so we're done
            break;
        }
        // swap child and parent items
        swap(p, i);

        // and then move up one level
        i = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I updated my code, but i still have one question above. If you can help, i appreciate @jim

Comment: thank you sir, do you recommend any articles that I need to read ? just to improve my knowledge, I understand the fundamental of Java, but  I often have a hard to read and understand the long code.

Comment: @TroyNguyen I wrote a series of blog posts on priority queues and heaps a few years back. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/12/18/posting-the-heap-code/ for a list of those articles. The code samples are in C#, but you should be able to understand them if you know Java.

Comment: `public void changeKey(Student s, double newGPA)` this is the method I like to put in my code, if I like to change the value of the node, should I delete the node first and then add the new node into the old node then compare it with parent? or any ways to change it?

Comment: @TroyNguyen You first change the value. Then check to see if the new value is smaller than the parent. If so, then move the item up the heap. Otherwise, call `maxHeapify` to (potentially) move it down in the heap.

Comment: when you say "change the value", what's the method should I use ?

Comment: @TroyNguyen You search the `Student` collection to find the item, change its value, and then re-adjust the heap as I described. If you need more detail, I would suggest posting a new question.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm searching in java API8 to find a method. Also, I create a new question.