# Using assertEquals in Junit test. How can I correct it?

Tags: java, junit

```
public class MyTestCase {
    private MaxHeap testHeap;
    MaxHeap Student = new MaxHeap();

       @Before
       public void setUp() throws Exception
       {
           testHeap = new MaxHeap(10);
           testHeap.insert(new Student("Susan", 60, 3.5));
           testHeap.insert(new Student("Ben", 70, 3.4));
           testHeap.insert(new Student("Reed", 120, 4.0));
           testHeap.insert(new Student("Troy", 90, 1.1));
           testHeap.insert(new Student("Johnny", 50, 2.3));

       }
       @Test

       public void testInsert() {
           Student.name("Ciroc");
           Student.setGPA(3.3);
           Student.setUnits(75);

           double testCase = MaxHeap.insert(students);
           assertEquals(3.3, testHeap.extractMax().gpa(), 0.0);
       }
}
```

I like to use JUnit test, to test the insert method in the heap, if the student with higher GPA will replace the student with the lower GPA. This is the first time I use JUnit. I'm not sure if it's right, please correct me. Thank you.

Here is the link for MaxHeap and Student class [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593477/questions-inserting-in-heapsort/48594341?noredirect=1#comment84222417_48594341)

Comment: yes that's the right way. you are passing the tolerance limit as third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's correct.

```
@param expected - expected value
@param actual - the value to check against <code>expected</code>
@param delta - the maximum delta between <code>expected</code> and  

static public void assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta) {...}
```

Comment: but when I run the test, it said `Class not found MyTestCase
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyTestCase`